# Finding difference in day between today's date and a entered date

Tags: python

I am currently trying to construct a function that takes a date string and returns the number of days from that date until now. It will return 0 if it detects that the format is wrong, with the input date string format being **Day/Month/Year** (e.g. 12/3/21). The number should be negative if it is a past date (e.g. today is 14/3/21, the input date is 3/3/21, the function should return -11). This is my code so far but it keeps returning 0:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def convert_date(input_date):
    try:
        current_date = date.today()
        
        d1 = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%d/%m/%y')
        d2 = datetime.strptime(current_date, '%d/%m/%y')
        delta = d1 - d2
        return delta.day
    
    except:
        return 0
```

I am very unsure on what I have done wrong, as I have done a lot of research but have not found a solution. Hopefully someone can provide further clarification, thanks

(Also i am using the Datetime package)

Comment: `current_date` is a `date` object. You do not need `strptime` it

Comment: A simple tip: comment the `try` and the `except` and see what's going wrong; make it fail loudly. You're silencing all exceptions, so how could you find out? Also, use an IDE and execute your code step by step (VS code, Spyder and lots of other IDEs and editors have this functionality)

Comment: Yet, do not use bare `except:`. Explicitly specify the exception to catch, `except ValueError:` this case. There are multiple exceptions, including AttributeError, TypeError. They are not caused by wrong inputs but typo or wrong types.

Comment: Although `current_date` is a `date` object, you can't do `datetime` arithmetic with it without converting it to a `datetime` object. Try `d2 = datetime.combine(current_date, time.min)` (you'll need to import `time`). Also you need `delta.days`, note the `s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are basics and you need to understand datetime module well. Hope this solves your problem.

```py
from datetime import datetime


def convert_date(input_date):
    try:
        current_date = datetime.today()

        d1 = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%d/%m/%y')

        delta = d1 - current_date
        return delta.days
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```